# Android async task in service freezes UI

Tags: android, user-interface, asynchronous, service, freeze

I've got a service that is running an ASync task. 
This task is causing my UI to freeze (even though it shouldn't).

```
public class StartMonitoringRegionsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
                @Override public void onServiceReady() {
                    try {
                        for(int i = 0; i <= METRO_VEHICLE_REFERENCE_LIMIT; i++) {
                            beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region("vehicle region", PROXIMITY_UUID, i, null));
                        }
                        for(int i = METRO_VEHICLE_REFERENCE_LIMIT+1; i <= METRO_STOP_REFERENCE_LIMIT; i++) {
                            beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region("stop region", PROXIMITY_UUID, i, null));
                        }
                        for(int i = METRO_STOP_REFERENCE_LIMIT+1; i <= BUS_VEHICLE_REFERENCE_LIMIT; i++) {
                            beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region("region", PROXIMITY_UUID, i, null));
                        }
                        for(int i = BUS_VEHICLE_REFERENCE_LIMIT+1; i <= BUS_STOP_REFERENCE_LIMIT; i++) {
                            beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region("stop region", PROXIMITY_UUID, i, null));
                        }
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Error while starting monitoring");
                    }
                }
            });
        return null;
    }
}
```

To start the task I call:

```
new StartMonitoringRegionsTask().execute();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a guess, perhaps something in the connect method is synchronized and is locking the beaconManager instance, then if you're trying to call another beaconManager method from the main thread, it might be freezing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code kind of looks fine, the problem might be in the API you use or in code you have not shown us. You can find on google similar question:

https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/issues/104

so if you are doing anything heavy in `onBeaconsDiscovered` then move it to separate thread - actually `AsyncTask`, the `beaconManager.connect` I suppose can be called from UI thread.